# Custom filter between two dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, wordpress

I am trying to filter the data between two dates. I was trying to fix it but I could not complete it. Can anyone help me?

My html:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="from_date">
<input type="date" ng-model="to_date">
```

My ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in outlets | dateRange:from_date:to_date">
    <td>{{ item.offerID }}</td>
    <td>{{ parseDate(item.startDate) | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}</td>
```

My script:

```
 app.filter('dateRange', function () {
    return function (items, fromDate, toDate) {
        var filtered = [];
        console.log(fromDate, toDate);
        var from_date = Date.parse(fromDate);
        var to_date = Date.parse(toDate);
        angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
            if (item.startDate > from_date && item.startDate < to_date) {
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        });
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

jason data from server:

```
{
"offerID": "1"
, "merchant": "Rifa Ladies Salon"
, "outelt": "Rifa Ladies Salon Business Bay"
, "offer": "Rifa Ladies Salon- Offer 1"
, "offerStatus": "LIVE"
, "startDate": "2016-07-12"}
```

Comment: Dear Fetra, i have updated a json data from server. i hope now you can help me.

Comment: i do not have the Date.parse() function. do i need a seperate function for that??

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing by Date.parse, but in  your filter comparison:

```
if (item.startDate > from_date && item.startDate < to_date) {
```

**item.startDate** is a '**YYYY-MM-DD'** format,  **from_date** and **to_date** are **timestamp** by Date.parse(),

So you just need to choose will you use Date.parse() or not? This is your fix:

```
if (Date.parse(item.startDate) > from_date && Date.parse(item.startDate) < to_date) {
}
```

Complete filter:

```
app.filter('dateRange', function () {
    return function (items, fromDate, toDate) {
        var filtered = [];
        var from_date = Date.parse(fromDate);
        var to_date = Date.parse(toDate);
        if (!to_date || !from_date) {
            return items;
        }
        angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
            if (Date.parse(item.startDate) > from_date && Date.parse(item.startDate) < to_date) {
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        });
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

working fiddle: http://plnkr.co/edit/SPnN4wptw1Sltsp1lawD?p=preview

Comment: Really i don't know still it's not working. whenever i remove my dateRange filter from the ng-repeat i am able to get the data from the server. but if i include  dateRange i am getting a syntax error on the console.